# Eclipse Plugin: Getting install location of source bundle

Tags: eclipse, osgi

I am creating an IClasspathContainer that access an installed OSGi Bundle (Eclipse Plugin) withing eclipse. I get the IPath for the bundle by

```
    Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle(pluginId);
    fullPath = FileLocator.getBundleFile(
    return Path.fromOSString(fullPath);bundle).getAbsolutePath();
```

However I also want to offer the sources if the source bundle is installed. The source bundle is named by eclipse e.g. for a plugin *org.example.myplugin* the source bundle is named *org.example.myplugin.source*.

Does anybody know how to access the source bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to find an OSGi bundle by it's symbolic name, but one can easily do that oneself by looping through all bundles.

```
    BundleContext bundleContext = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()).getBundleContext();
    String requestedName = bundleContext.getProperty(Constants.BUNDLE_SYMBOLICNAME) + ".source";
    Bundle sourceBundle = null;
    for(Bundle bundle : bundleContext.getBundles())
    {
        String name = bundle.getBundleContext().getProperty(Constants.BUNDLE_SYMBOLICNAME);
        if(name != null && name.equals(requestedName))
        {
            sourceBundle = bundle;
            break;
        }
    }
```

The location of the bundle can be accessed as:

```
        sourceBundle.getLocation();
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. No source bundles are returned by `getBundles`, at least in my test plugin (running using an Eclipse JUnit launch configuration). Do I need to add something special to that launch configuration?